# Building MuPdf and registering document handlers

Tags: c++, mupdf

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22559733/1673140) we have a question, an answer and some happy people.

But I've got a different situation,
I'm coding in C++ and I'm going to build MuPdf myself.
So, when i add `fz_register_document_handlers` function before `fz_open_document_with_stream` I'll get 5 unresolved external symbols for these

```
_opj_image_destroy (2 times)
_opj_copy_image_header
_opj_image_comp_header
_opj_image_create
```

I can get rid of 3 of them by linking `openjpeg\libopenjpeg\image.c` but `_opj_image_destroy` is stock on my compiling error list!

**[UPDATE]**

Mupdf version: 1.6
I don't know that it's a right way or not but I created a visual studio project, named Native and put Mupdf source in it and try to compile.
Then i'm using it's header in other c++ project (and using declare "C" in it) and linked Native to it.
It works fine until i trying to open a file as a stream and not file address.
So, my project failed with this error: **"No document handlers registered"**.
This error is caused by `document.c` file.

I searched and find the page which was linked above and I changed the source.
The compile errors appeared after that change!

Thanks for your help and sorry for my English...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you haven't said what version of MuPDF you are using. I'm going to assume you're using the latest version from git (currently 1.6 as of 1 Feb 2015).

Secondly, you've not told us anything of use about how you're building MuPDF. Without knowing exactly what you've changed, it's hard to speculate what you're doing wrong.

If you're compiling vanilla .c files with a c++ compiler then you probably need to do some wrapping of files with extern "C" declarations.

Feel free to get in touch on the #ghostscript irc channel and tell us more.

[Update]

It sounds to me like you are missing the openjpeg decoder. You can't just add a single file from the openjpeg source and expect it to magically work.

Why are you creating your own Visual Studio project when we provide one for you already? platform/win32/mupdf.sln